# Grouping by two factor variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to plot the two different type of production for five different groups. I can generate the plot and it already looks ok, although the ordering in the final ggplot is not as I would like to have it.
I found the solution with `arrange()`, but although the ordering in this step is correct the final result is different again.
I would like to have the grouping that for each group (1, 2, 3, 4, NA) the two different types of production are right on top of each other.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
DT <- structure(list(Year.Quarter = structure(c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                                          2015, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.5, 
                                          2015.5, 2015.5, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2015.75, 2015.75, 2015.75, 2015.75, 
                                          2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016.25, 2016.25, 2016.25, 2016.25, 
                                          2016.25), class = "yearqtr")
                                        , Group = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 
                                                  1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 
                                                  4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA)
                                        , Conventional.Prod = c(11.78, 7.31, 7.34, 9.44, 28.72, 11.32, 5.27, 7.47, 8.08, 27.14, 11.49, 
                                                                4.65, 7.63, 7.07, 25.93, 10.69, 3.68, 6.96, 6.72, 18.31, 9.28, 
                                                                 3.69, 6.86, 6.34, 19.14, 9.25, 3.69, 6.9, 6.16, 17.7)
                                       , Unconventional.Prod = c(15.22, 10.69, 7.66, 15.56, 30.28, 15.68, 10.73, 7.53, 15.92, 29.86, 
                                                        13.51, 10.35, 7.37, 15.93, 28.07, 13.31, 10.32, 7.04, 16.28, 
                                25.69, 12.72, 9.31, 7.14, 16.66, 25.86, 12.75, 9.31, 7.1, 16.84, 24.3))
                        , .Names = c("Year.Quarter", "Group", "Conventional.Prod", "Unconventional.Prod"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                      "data.frame"))
data.table::melt(DT,
                 , id.vars = c("Year.Quarter", "Group")
                 , measure.vars = c("Conventional.Prod", "Unconventional.Prod")
) %>% arrange(Year.Quarter, Group, variable) %>%  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = Year.Quarter, y = value, color = variable, fill = as.factor(Group))) +
        geom_area(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
        #geom_line(aes(x = Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter ,y = value)) +
        theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
        scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Y-Q%q",n = 8, expand = c(0,0))
```

The ordering after the `arrange` step is as intended:

```
Year.Quarter     Group      variable       value
1:      2015 Q1     1   Conventional.Prod  7.31
2:      2015 Q1     1 Unconventional.Prod 10.69
3:      2015 Q1     2   Conventional.Prod 11.78
4:      2015 Q1     2 Unconventional.Prod 15.22
5:      2015 Q1     3   Conventional.Prod  9.44
6:      2015 Q1     3 Unconventional.Prod 15.56
7:      2015 Q1     4   Conventional.Prod  7.34
8:      2015 Q1     4 Unconventional.Prod  7.66
9:      2015 Q1    NA   Conventional.Prod 28.72
10:     2015 Q1    NA Unconventional.Prod 30.28
```

But the ordering in the final plot is somehow reversed again, so that the production is the major group.
[image: Plot with wrong grouping]

Comment: I am not sure if the problem might be solvable by using `aes_group_order`, but not sure how to properly implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `fill` before `color` in the call to `ggplot()` is a quick way to do what I think you want:

```
# Not repeating all the code from your example, but change this line:
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Year.Quarter, y = value, fill = as.factor(Group), color = variable))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, yeah that's what I was looking for. I tried nearly all possible combinations of fill and color, but I never changed the order. It just never occured to me that this might make a difference...

Answer (score 2):

Would you be interested in something like this? It's not exactly how you expected but it gives a nice visualization to your data.

```
data.table::melt(DT,
                 , id.vars = c("Year.Quarter", "Group")
                 , measure.vars = c("Conventional.Prod", "Unconventional.Prod")
) %>% ggplot(data = ., aes(x = Year.Quarter, y = value, fill = as.factor(Group))) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Y-Q%q") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(. ~ variable) +
  theme_bw()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a alot, it's a nice representation. But I am more interested to show the diverging pattern between the two production types per group. So that's why I would like to have the production right next to each other for each group.

Comment: How about replacing `geom_bar` code in my approach with `geom_area(stat = "identity")`? Also see the difference after adding `position = "fill"` option in it (notice the change in y-axis). I think it should fulfill your requirement to some extent.

Comment: I like the idea of a facet plot, I'll try to go with that, although I changed `facet_grid( variable ~.) +` to  `facet_grid( variable ~.) +` in order to make it easier to compare the development over time.

Comment: Glad that you liked the solution!

Comment: Although I don't want to mark it as an answer, since it's not really solving the question, but just adds a possible data visualization.